# Showing nearby markers

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin, google-maps-markers

I have defined markers of a place on the map and i want to show only a nearby marker on my entered location

```
    val nangka = LatLng(14.669100, 121.108140)
    val north_edsa = LatLng(14.596530, 121.059441)
    val mandaluyong = LatLng(14.590030, 121.034700)
    val payatas = LatLng(14.628710, 121.063900)
    val bay_area = LatLng(14.537208, 120.990720)
    val paranaque = LatLng(14.447820, 121.023040)
    val muntinlupa = LatLng(14.590030, 121.034700)
    val feliz = LatLng(14.628710, 121.063900)
    val manila = LatLng(14.577701, 120.983741)
    val makati = LatLng(14.551714, 121.027288)
    val las_pinas = LatLng(14.453614, 120.975966)
    val katipunan = LatLng(14.639077, 121.074214)
    val raymundo = LatLng(14.572139, 121.083775)
    val commonwealth = LatLng(14.663149, 121.068543)
    val alabang = LatLng(14.428302, 121.027184)
    val antipolo = LatLng(14.5884681, 121.1574247)
    val main = LatLng(14.5890657, 121.07890606)
    val fairview = LatLng(14.7363483, 121.06002163)
    val low_antipolo = LatLng(14.62467319, 121.12265825)
    val gateway = LatLng(14.6219187, 121.05293074)
    val angono = LatLng(14.53093443, 121.15457696)
    val tandang_sora = LatLng(14.67962335, 121.01988032)
    val valenzuela = LatLng(14.68605018, 120.97691678)
```

Comment: There are a lot of missing information here. What's the context ? Where do you want this indication to be shown ? What is a _Nearby Marker_ ? What's the reference point (GPS location, arbitrary coordinate) ? ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Location::distanceBetween`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween(double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float%5B%5D)) to get the distance from a point A (user location) and point B (other location)

You should add all markers to Google Map and keep the instance on each marker, then, compare the distance from the user location with each marker and change the visibility state

```
    val result = FloatArray(1) // First element will contains the distance between the locations
    val currentUserLocation: Location = getCurrentUserLocation()
    aMarkerList.forEach {
        val currentLatLng = it.getPosition()
        // Calculates the distance between two points
        Location.distanceBetween(
            currentUserLocation.latitude,
            currentUserLocation.longitude,
            currentLatLng.latitude,
            currentLatLng.longitude,
            result
        )
        val distance = result[0] // You could use result[0] directly
        it.isVisible = distance <= YOUR_DISTANCE
    }
```

*Update*

Once Google Maps is ready, you could store the markers to manipulate them after:

```
val nangka = LatLng(14.669100, 121.108140)
val northEdsa = LatLng(14.596530, 121.059441)

Marker nangkaMarker = mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(nangka));
Marker northEdsaMarker = mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(northEdsa));

aMarkerList.add(nangkaMarker)
aMarkerList.add(northEdsaMarker)
// And son on...
```

I'm pretty sure, next link will be helpful https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/marker#customize_a_marker

Comment: `private fun displayEnteredLocation(location: LatLng) {
        val markerOptions = MarkerOptions().position(location)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_entered_location))
        mMap.addMarker(markerOptions)
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(location, 12f))

    }`

Comment: this is the location that user entered. from a search activity

Comment: I have updated the code with the a simple idea to store markers in a `List<Marker>`

Comment: Thank you very much this solves my problem. But i got one last question. Is it possible  or how to store the LatLng value into the Location?

Comment: It's nothing @jeiboi. Now, I'm not sure I have catch your idea about store LatLng into the Location, could you explain a little bit more?

Comment: for example `val enteredLocation:Location`
how can i put this `LatLng(14.669100, 121.108140)` on enteredLocation
is it posible?